# How to compare Between Image Value and String

Tags: android, imageview

Im new on Android studio,ihve value data tht i get from Intent

```
Integer resourceId = (Integer)g.getItemAtPosition(item.getItemId()); 
Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ImageDetail.class);
k.putExtra("id",resourceId);
startActivity(k);
```

On receiver

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(linearLayout);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
Intent k =getIntent();
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(k.getExtras().getInt("id"));
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

(I got value "res/drawable/ikan.jpg")

When i try to compare textview and String its fail...

```
 if (textView.equals("res/drawable/ikan.jpg")){
      //kondisi  
 }
```

Comment: Why would you compare textView and a String? If you wish to compare the text from your textView with a string, you should call textView.getText().toString().equals("res/drawable/ikan.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `String` and `TextView`. You can extract value into a variable and then compare it.

```
Intent k =getIntent();
String extra = String.k.getExtras().getString("id");
if (extra.equals("res/drawable/ikan.jpg")){
  //...  
}
```

Comment: This way he would be comparing Integer and String.
I guess <? instanceof Context>.getResources().getString(extra) should be called before comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
 if (textView.getText().toString().equals("res/drawable/ikan.jpg")){
      //kondisi  
 }
```